# Uploaded files getting deleted while redeploying in Openshift server

Tags: ubuntu, openshift, openshift-enterprise

After pushing the whole application, The whole application is working fine. Then I upload some files to my uploads folder via my web interface.

If I push the code via git, All the files in uploads folder is deleting automaticaly. Is there a way to stop this in my openshift server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application should be storing any persistent files in the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`, which is usually ~/app-root/data. Your application is likely storing these "uploads" into the `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`, where your code lives. This directory is overwritten with your new code every time you `git push`.

You need to configure your application to store the uploads in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR to store them persistently.

Comment: How to move my uploads folder to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR ?

Comment: That depends on your application code. You will need to modify where `uploads` are stored so that the uploads will be placed in the data directory. Alternatively, you can set up a symlink to the data directory in your build action hook. See this forum post (assuming you are using wordpress): https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-find-wordpress-uploads-folder

Comment: I agree with @Timbabwe, symlinks are the way to go, you can check out the WordPress quickstart for an idea of how the symlinks would work and where to create them: https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy

Answer (score 1):

on your root wordpress local create a dir for action hook

```
mkdir -p .openshift/action_hooks
```

then create deploy hook

```
vim .openshift/action_hooks/deploy
```

paste this

```
#!/bin/bas
echo "Creating symlink folder of uploads" 
if [ ! -d ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ]; then
    mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads
fi
ln -svf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}wp-content/uploads
```

**NOTE**: The .openshift/action_hooks/deploy hook is not executable, to make it executable:

On Windows:   `git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`

On Linux/OSX: `chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`

add changes, commit and push.